# How to render Drupal 7 Date Field

Tags: drupal-7

How can I properly render exclusively `end date` from the Drupal 7 `Date field` in template file?

```
$node->field_start_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]` (is it correct?)
```

I can get to raw values but I want it to get formatted etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_end_datetime'));
```

field_view_field: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7